# Is there a Pandas DataFrame implementation that loads lazily records from a table in a HDF5 file?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I am trying to convert millions of existing HDF5 files to Parquet format. Problem is that both input and output can't fit memory so I need means to process the input data (tables in a HDF5 file) in chunks and somehow have Pandas DataFrame that lazily load these chunks while [fastparquet write function](http://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write) reads from it.

Pandas read_hdf() and HDF5Store's select *do* take chunksize as parameter, but they do not return usable dataframe. Without the *chunksize* parameter the program runs out of memory because Pandas loads the whole dataset in memory.

Comment: `pd.read_hdf(..., chunksize=N)` and `pd.HDFStore.select(..., chunksize=N)` DO return usable dataframes

Comment: In my case (pandas 0.20.1, tables 3.2.2) I am getting Panda's TableIterator, and when I try to use it as dataframe I am getting ValueErrors because of shape...

Comment: I'd suggest you to post a complete error traceback...

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?